# Max Row and Col for Animating Sprite in Andengine

Tags: android, image, andengine, animated

Hi All, I want to animate a Sprite in Andengine , I have Used:

```
this.mSnapdragonTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createTiledFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this,"arrow.png", 10, 10);
```

As shown above in code, I have a 10x10 spritesheet. This spritesheet represents 100 frames of animation.

The image, for reference:
[image: spritesheet]

My issue is if I draw this animated sprite, I see a black patch instead of animated image, despite the same technique working properly for 2x3, and 4x2 spritesheets.

Is my issue because 10x10 is too large? What is the maximum number of rows and
columns which can be used for this method of animation?

Comment: how big is the image - and how big is mBitmapTextureAtlas?

Comment: All of same size 300x280 each image

Comment: Does it work if your image dimensions are powers of 2? (Try resizing the image to 256x256) Hint: If you are using GLES1 this is the issue.

Comment: ok my actuall size is 300x280.. but let me try this

Comment: black boxes means the atlas you have created is not enough.If your sprite sheet size is 300x280  then create an atlas with 512x512 the powr 2.As  MickLH  said in GLES1 its an issue but i  used gles2 anchor center for my project but i had faced this issue in nexus 7 tab.So its safe to use 2 power atlas.

Comment: If your image frames are only different in visual content size, I will simply use scale modifier instead of sprite sheet.

Comment: I agree with @playmaker420 - it's likely a lack of atlas space that is causing the issue. Is the spritesheet 300x280 - or is each image in the sheet 300x280? Hopefully the former as 100 images at 300x280 would be a massive issue